# Looking for a readable way to execute multiple tasks in Parallel

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm looking for a good way to run async methods in parallel, without having the burden of keeping my Task objects and getting their results from their task, because I feel this makes for less readable code.

I know I can run two async methods in parallel like this:

```
var t1 = RunAsync1();
var t2 = RunAsync2();

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2)

var result1 = t1.Result;
var result2 = t2.Result;
```

For a website that makes a lot of API calls to external services that have nothing to do with each other, I was trying to make this more readable for my fellow developers and take away some of the burden of keeping the `t1`, `t2`, ... variables.

I came up with the following, but don't know if this is a good way to handle this. Are there downsides to passing my ModelClass to `SetResultOfTask1` and `SetResultOfTask2` methods, like possible memory leaks maybe or something else?

```
public async Task GetResult() 
{
   var model = new ModelClass();
   await ExecuteInParallel(SetResultOfTask1(model), SetResultOfTask2(model));

   //I can now proceed knowing that model.AsyncResult1 and model.AsyncResult2 should be filled in.
}


private async Task ExecuteInParallel(params Task[] tasks)
{
  return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task SetResultOfTask1(ModelClass m) 
{
  m.AsyncResult1 = await GetAsync1();
}

private async Task SetResultOfTask2(ModelClass m)
{
  m.AsyncResult2 = await GetAsync2();
}
```

Or is there perhaps a better way to handle this that keeps its readability?
Thank you for your thoughts and advice!

**UPDATE**
A fair point was made that the method `ExecuteInParallel` doesn't have any value, so this can be removed for the sake of readability.

My idea was to avoid a method that looks like this :

```
public async Task<ModelClass> GetModel()
{
   var t1 = RunAsync1();
   var t2 = RunAsync2();
   var t3 = GetProductTypesAsync();
   var t4 = GetUserInformationAsync();

   await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
   
   var model = new ModelClass();
   model.Type1 = t1.Result;
   model.Type2 = t2.Result;
   if (t3.Result == null) {
      //do something else
   }

   foreach (var productType in t4.Result) {  
     //get some more information per product type 
     model.ProductTypes.Add(productType)
   }

   return model;
}
```

and replace it with a method that is more expressive in what is happening, like this. As an outside programmer, I can just read what's happening to construct the model.

```
public async Task<ModelClass> GetModel()
{
   var model = new ModelClass();
   
   //these four methods have nothing to do with one another, other than their end result must end up in my instance of ModelClass, which is why I got tempted into trying to execute this in parallel.

   await GetGeneralInformationAboutTheProduct(model);
   await LoadProductTypes(model);
   await LoadUserInformation(model);
   await LoadShoppingCartInformation(model);

   return model;
}
```

Comment: To me, your second example is just way more confusing. At least I'm familiar with the patter in the first example.

Comment: That's just obfuscates what is happening. The initial code uses documented stuff used by many programmers that way so it easy to find whats meant by it. Can you say the same for your "readable" code?

Comment: What you implemented there is in my opinion is worse than the 1st code example, because its usage would result in an equivalent code as your 1st code example but with _less_ degree of readability. Basically you turn `Task.WhenAll` into `ExecuteInParallel`, which is just misleading, because it does not execute anything, it just awaits tasks.

Comment: Then you turn a straightforward `var result1 = t1.Result`/`m.AsyncResult1 = task1.Result` into `SetResultOfTask1(ModelClass m)` which also is not improving readability either, but quite the opposite, because what is Task1 with respect to SetResultOfTask1 and where exactly does the result of that task end up in the ModelClass? So, now you need to create all that documentation for your stuff that you wouldn't need to do if you and your mates/colleagues would just stick with the _self-explanatory_ (and therefore readable) `m.AsyncResult1 = task1.Result` without "hiding" it in SetResultOfTask1.

Comment: The original is readable enough and far better than the alternative. If all tasks return the same type T `await Task.WhenAll` will return a `T[]` with the results in the order of the tasks: `var results=await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,...);`

Comment: @StevenLemmens What is the *real* problem you want to solve? It's obvious *in this simple example where the tasks are already available as a collection* that the proposed alternative is worse. Are you trying to simplify a more complex scenario?

Comment: Its worth pointing out that as long as you initiate both tasks before you await either, the use of `Task.WhenAll` is not necessary to enable parallel behaviour. You could just await them one after another, as long as the awaits come after the calls.

Comment: If you don't want the variables, *and* the tasks return the same type, `var results=await Task.WhenAll(RunAsync1(), RunAsync2(),....);`. OTOH, if you want you eg make concurrent HTTP calls there are *bigger* concerns that retrieving the results. Concurrency limits, retries etc require a *different* way of programming. Eg using a pipeline that processes at most N URL requests at any time, Polly for retries. The way to make this more readable is to use Dataflow blocks or Channels to construct pipelines

Comment: If you have multiple operations that need to complete before you can proceed you may need a Batch or Command class. This has nothing to do with tasks. It's a way of abstracting a set of operations to hide its execution details from callers, and allow it to be handled as a single unit.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you all make very valid points. I've just added a small example to illustrate what I mean by better readability

Comment: If you changed your refactored last example, with nice names, to potentially run the tasks in parallel, you'd want to be sure that none of tasks collided on the properties of the model they changed. I much prefer a functional style rather than mutating a parameter, unless performance is a special concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable parallel execution of tasks you could write your method like this.

Note: this doesn't mean that the code will execute in parallel, just that it could.

Task execution can start as soon as the call is made, the choice of what task is executed when should not be your concern.

```
public async Task<ModelClass> GetModel()
{
   var t1 = RunAsync1();
   var t2 = RunAsync2();
   var t3 = GetProductTypesAsync();
   var t4 = GetUserInformationAsync();
   
   var model = new ModelClass();
   model.Type1 = await t1;
   model.Type2 = await t2;
   var t3Result = await t3;
   if (t3Result  == null) {
      //do something else
   }

   foreach (var productType in await t4) {  
     //get some more information per product type 
     model.ProductTypes.Add(productType)
   }

   return model;
}
```

This has the benefit of being familiar to the C# population and allowing greater concurrency and less exception aggregation. This should also be more flexible with regards to `ValueTask<T>`. Additionally, you make no use of the `Task.Result` property, which is often regarded with concern and a potential code smell.

Comment: I really like this example. I've been making my life way to complicated. As soon as I refactored this so `t3` became getProductInformation for instance, my code become much more readable. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the original code is just fine, but if you really wanted to you could use tuple return types to do something like this:

```
public static class MyRun
{
    public static async Task<(T1 r1, T2 r2)> WhenAll<T1, T2>(Task<T1> t1, Task<T2> t2)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);

        return (t1.Result, t2.Result);
    }

    public static async Task<(T1 r1, T2 r2, T3 r3)> WhenAll<T1, T2, T3>(Task<T1> t1, Task<T2> t2, Task<T3> t3)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);

        return (t1.Result, t2.Result, t3.Result);
    }

    // Etc.
}
```

Note that you'd have to add a new overload for each number of parameters, which is somewhat laborious...

Anyway, after doing that let's suppose you have the following methods:

```
static async Task<string> task1()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    return "task1";
}

static async Task<int> task2(int value)
{
    await Task.Delay(200);
    return value * 420;
}

static async Task<double> task3(double value)
{
    await Task.Delay(300);
    return Math.Sqrt(value);
}
```

You could call those and get the results in one line like so:

```
var (r1, r2, r3) = await MyRun.WhenAll(task1(), task2(10), task3(64));
```

But as I said, I prefer the normal approach.